# Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll not there in Windows phone project add references dialog?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to build a Windows phone 7.1 project on Windows 8 , which was earlier built on Windows7.
on windows 8 i started getting this error, reference could not found for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework'

am i missing something simple here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the SDK and reinstalling did the trick! Thanks